# Lua Error: Main.lua:131: attempt to index local ‘up’ (a nil value) stack traceback:

Tags: lua, runtime-error, coronasdk

I've a game project due in the next month(simple maze game) but I keep running into this error. I'd really appreciate it if someone took a look at it. I'm new to Lua so it's probably very simple. The error seems to be originating around line 131. I've put line 131 between a load of stars (*****...). You'd make my day if you took a few minutes to look at it. :) The error is : Main.lua:131: attempt to index local ‘up’ (a nil value) stack traceback:

```
     local screenWidth = display.contentWidth
        local screenHeight = display.contentHeight
        local controllerWidth = screenWidth / 6
        local rightMargin = 30
        local maze = {
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        }
        maze.rows = table.getn(maze)
        maze.columns = table.getn(maze[1])
        maze.xStart, maze.yStart = 1, 1
        maze.xFinish, maze.yFinish = 24, 7

        local grid = {}
        grid.xSquares = maze.columns
        grid.ySquares = maze.rows
        grid.totalWidth = screenWidth - controllerWidth - rightMargin
        grid.squareSize = grid.totalWidth / grid.xSquares
        grid.xStart = controllerWidth
        grid.yStart = 60
        grid.displayGroup = display.newGroup()
        grid.displayGroup.x = grid.xStart
        grid.displayGroup.y = grid.yStart

        grid.functions = {
          left = function(gridSquare)
                if gridSquare.x == 0 then
                    return gridSquare
                else
                    return grid[gridSquare.y][gridSquare.x - 1]
                end
            end,
          right = function(gridSquare)
                if gridSquare.x + 1 == grid.xSquares then
                    return gridSquare
                else
                    return grid[gridSquare.y][gridSquare.x + 1]
                end
            end,
          above = function(gridSquare)
                if gridSquare.y == 0 then
                    return gridSquare
                else
                    return grid[gridSquare.y - 1][gridSquare.x]
                end
            end,
          below = function(gridSquare)
                if gridSquare.y + 1 == grid.ySquares then
                    return gridSquare
                else
                    return grid[gridSquare.y + 1][gridSquare.x]
                end
            end,
        }

        for y = 0, grid.ySquares - 1 do
          grid[y] = {y = y}
          for x = 0, grid.xSquares - 1 do
            grid[y][x] = {x = x, y = y}
            local rect = display.newRect(grid.displayGroup,
                grid.squareSize * x, grid.squareSize * y,
                grid.squareSize, grid.squareSize)
            if maze[y + 1][x + 1] == 0 then
                    rect:setFillColor(245, 215, 98)
                else
                    grid[y][x].wall = true
                    rect:setFillColor(32, 96, 32, 255)
                end
            grid[y][x].displayObject = rect
            grid[y][x].left = grid.functions.left
                grid[y][x].right = grid.functions.right
                grid[y][x].above = grid.functions.above
                grid[y][x].below = grid.functions.below
          end
        end
        grid[maze.yStart - 1][maze.xStart - 1].start = true
        grid[maze.yStart - 1][maze.xStart - 1].displayObject:setFillColor(192, 192, 255)
        grid[maze.yFinish - 1][maze.xFinish - 1].displayObject:setFillColor(192, 128, 128)
        grid[maze.yStart - 1][maze.xStart - 1].start = true
        grid[maze.yFinish - 1][maze.xFinish - 1].finish = true

        local runner = { image = "runner.png" }
        function runner:enter(gridSquare)
          if self.displayObject == nil then
                self.displayObject = display.newImageRect(grid.displayGroup,
                self.image, grid.squareSize, grid.squareSize)
                self.displayObject:setFillColor(92, 92, 92)
            end
          self.displayObject.x = gridSquare.displayObject.x
            self.displayObject.y = gridSquare.displayObject.y
          self.gridSquare = gridSquare
          self.x = gridSquare.x
            self.y = gridSquare.y
          if self.gridSquare.finish then
                finish()
            end
        end
        function runner:canEnter(gridSquare)
            return gridSquare.wall == nil
        end

        local controlCenterX = controllerWidth / 2
        local controlCenterY = screenHeight - screenHeight / 5
        local controlCenterRadius = controllerWidth / 2 - rightMargin
        local upDownWidth = 27
        local upDownHeight = 60
        local leftRightWidth = 60
        local leftRightHeight = 27
        local controls = {
            up    = {},
            down  = {},
            right = {},
            left  = {},
        }
        controls.displayGroup = display.newGroup()
        local circlePad = display.newCircle(controls.displayGroup,
            controlCenterX, controlCenterY, controlCenterRadius)
          circlePad:setFillColor(128, 128, 128)

******
    local up = display.newImageRect(controls.displayGroup, "arrow_up.png",
            upDownWidth, upDownHeight)
        up.x = controlCenterX
        up.y = controlCenterY - upDownHeight / 2
        controls.up.displayObject = up
******
        local down = display.newImageRect(controls.displayGroup, "arrow_down.png",
          upDownWidth, upDownHeight)
        down.x = controlCenterX
        down.y = controlCenterY + upDownHeight / 2
        controls.down.displayObject = down
        local right = display.newImageRect(controls.displayGroup, "arrow_right.png",
            leftRightWidth, leftRightHeight)
        right.x = controlCenterX + leftRightWidth / 2
        right.y = controlCenterY
        controls.right.displayObject = right
        local left = display.newImageRect(controls.displayGroup, "arrow_left.png",
            leftRightWidth, leftRightHeight)
        left.x = controlCenterX - leftRightWidth / 2
        left.y = controlCenterY
        controls.left.displayObject = left
        controls.hide = function(controls)
            controls.displayGroup.isVisible = false
        end
        controls.show = function(controls)
            controls.displayGroup.isVisible = true
        end

        local function pressLeft(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                local nextSquare = runner.gridSquare:left()
                if runner:canEnter(nextSquare) then
                    runner:enter(nextSquare)
                end
            end
        end
        local function pressRight(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                local nextSquare  = runner.gridSquare:right()
                if runner:canEnter(nextSquare) then
                    runner:enter(nextSquare)
                end
            end
        end
        local function pressUp(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                local nextSquare  = runner.gridSquare:above()
                if runner:canEnter(nextSquare) then
                    runner:enter(nextSquare)
                end
            end
        end
        local function pressDown(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                local nextSquare  = runner.gridSquare:below()
                if runner:canEnter(nextSquare) then
                    runner:enter(nextSquare)
                end
            end
        end
        controls.left.displayObject:addEventListener("touch", pressLeft)
        controls.right.displayObject:addEventListener("touch", pressRight)
        controls.up.displayObject:addEventListener("touch", pressUp)
        controls.down.displayObject:addEventListener("touch", pressDown)
        local startButton = {}
        startButton.displayGroup = display.newGroup()
        startButton.displayObject = display.newCircle(startButton.displayGroup,
            controlCenterX, controlCenterY, controlCenterRadius)
          startButton.displayObject.strokeWidth = 6
        startButton.displayObject:setStrokeColor(244, 244, 64)
        startButton.text = display.newText(startButton.displayGroup,
            "Start", controlCenterX - controlCenterRadius + 20, controlCenterY - 18,
            native.systemFont, 24)
          startButton.text:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)
          startButton.touch = function(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                startButton:hide()
                start()
            end
        end
        startButton.displayGroup:addEventListener("touch", startButton.touch)
        startButton.show = function(button)
            button.displayGroup.isVisible = true
        end
        startButton.hide = function(button)
            button.displayGroup.isVisible = false
        end
        local playAgainButton = {}
        playAgainButton.displayGroup = display.newGroup()

        playAgainButton.displayObject = display.newCircle(playAgainButton.displayGroup,
            controlCenterX, controlCenterY, controlCenterRadius)
          playAgainButton.displayObject.strokeWidth = 6
        playAgainButton.displayObject:setStrokeColor(244, 244, 64)
        playAgainButton.text = display.newText(playAgainButton.displayGroup,
            "Again", controlCenterX - controlCenterRadius + 20, controlCenterY - 18,
            native.systemFont, 24)
          playAgainButton.text:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)
          playAgainButton.touch = function(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                playAgainButton:hide()
                play()
            end
        end
        playAgainButton.displayGroup:addEventListener("touch", playAgainButton.touch)
        playAgainButton.show = startButton.show
        playAgainButton.hide = startButton.hide

        function play()
          runner:enter(grid[maze.yStart - 1][maze.xStart - 1])
          playAgainButton:hide()
          controls:hide()
          startButton:show()
        end

        function start()
            controls:show()
        end

        function finish()
            controls:hide()
            playAgainButton:show()
        end
        play()
```

Comment: Looks like display.newImageRect() returns a `nil` for your `up`. Check if `controls.displayGroup` is initialized correctly, and if `arrow_up.png` can be found by your script.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work though

Comment: @BryanCarty Did you check what trexxet said?